# distributing form elements among different webpages,looks simple but not able to fix

Tags: html, php, javascript, jquery

This question is similar to my previous question but not the same ... please check out....I am using totaly 3 webpages; form elements are distributed among two pages, "eg1.html" and "eg2.html", but all the form elements should be submitted to "eg.php".

Here is the code for eg.php which accepts the form elements from both eg1.html and eg2.html:

```
$size=$_POST["fontsize"];
$label=$_POST["label"];
$age=$_POST["age"];
$sex =$_POST["sex"];
```

code for eg1.html

```
<html>     <body>
 <form action="eg.php" method="post">
 <input type="radio" name="fontsize" value="3"/>
 <a href="eg2.html">click here to select other options which includes age and sex</a>      
 <input type="radio" name="label" value="stacks"/>
 <input type="submit" name = "down" value = "down">
 </form>     </body>
```

Now what would be the code for eg2.html? Just check out sample partial html code, but needs to be completed

```
<input type="radio" name="age" value="3"/>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"/>`
```

The code should work exactly like this:

First user will open eg1.php he selects only one option that is "fontsize". Next he clicks on the "link to eg2.html" to select two more options "age" and "sex" after selecting. He will be redirected back to eg1.php where he has to select one more option that is "label". Then he will submit the form to eg.php. Which will hold all form elements those are 'fontsize' 'age' 'sex' and 'label'.

I have seen many website using this technique please check out cooltext.com where user will get an option to click on the font image which will redirect him to fonts page after selecting one of the fonts images he will be redirected back to homepage,where he can select some other form elements or form elements and finally submits the form. I have also seen many websites using this technique, I think this can be done using JQUERY/JavaScript but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the fonts choice page here http://cooltext.com/Fonts?LogoID=5&Field=Font is passing page-load variable to the generator page via a query string - the part of the url after ?. This query string has two parameters LogoID and Field.

e.g url onload from homepage http://cooltext.com/Logo-Design-Carved url of same page when loaded from the fonts page http://cooltext.com/Logo-Design?LogoID=5&Font=994 this url can be loaded from anywhere and the correct font will be set.

More info on the query string here:-

- [PHP Query String](http://ditio.net/2008/06/12/php-query-string/)
- [PHP Server Side Scripting Forum](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/12838.htm)
- [How to pass parameters as a query string to your PHP functions](http://professionaldilettante.com/how-to-pass-parameters-as-query-string-to-your-php-functions/2010.11.22)

Comment: Thanks for you reply guyz.... but by using "Michael Peacock's plugin " forms can be hided within one page ... but i need to distribute form element among two DIFFERENT pages ....NOT IN SAME PAGE....

Comment: @sri why do you need to distribute the form across several pages, it's not clear in your question?

Comment: i need to "distribute the form across several pages" bcos iam trying to desighn font picker where all fonts images will be loaded on different which will not reduce my homepage loading time....u can check cooltext they have used the same tecnique...

Comment: @sri if you take a look at the code in cooltext's homepage you'll see that all it's just a list of links, each of their generators has it's own homepage (for SEO/Social networks I'd imagine). So they only have a series of one page forms, not several forms split over two pages, this is why I posted the answer i did. If you post the question to stackoverflow one of their php hounds will be able to help you achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks for your reply checked the cooltext.com website not the home page ... click on any of the generators you will see "font image" when u click on font  image it takes you to the idfferent page where you can select any of the font ...after selecting you will be redirected back to the generator page finally you can submit the page.....

Comment: Right, I see its passing a variable back to the page via a query string from the look of things 'http://cooltext.com/Logo-Design?LogoID=5&Font=11611' so the page changes based on the incoming url.

Comment: thanks alot for your replies and answer toomanyairmiles 11... but i dont think its soo much complex ..check mklogo.com and check their font even they have used same tecnique...